# image gallery with auto flip

Tags: android, image-gallery, viewflipper

I am getting url of 10 images from server and I want it to display in a image view which flips the images automatically and also we can flip. I am not sure what to use whether image gallery or view flipper or some animation.

[image]

Comment: don't use gallery, it is already deprecated in Android from API level 16 onwards.

Comment: Then should i use view flipper?

Comment: yes, you should use view flipper, and if that doesn't work out for you, you can also try `HorizontalScrollView`.